# MediaPlayer does not play until seek() invocation

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create simple mp3 player in javafx but the audio does not play until I call seek() method on MediaPlayer instance.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/test.mp3").toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

        mediaPlayer.statusProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println(newValue);
            if(newValue == MediaPlayer.Status.READY) {
                mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
                mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Console output is:

```
READY
PLAYING
```

but player does not start playing the audio. When I add another else if with seek() method, then playback starts.

```
mediaPlayer.statusProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(newValue);
    if(newValue == MediaPlayer.Status.READY) {
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    } else if(newValue == MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING) {
        mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ONE);
    }
});
```

Is it bug in JavaFX or I am missing something? I use JDK11, adoptopenjdk build with openjfx on mac.

Comment: Does this happen with all MP3 files or just `test.mp3`?

Comment: I found that this is bug on macos, on windows everything works fine